# Case of System.Timers.Timer vs System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, timer

I have a console application that I want to use to send an email notification every day at some time (call it 06:00 local time). To do so at the moment I am using a `System.Timers.Timer` in the following way.

I have the following implementation of my service class:

```
public class PerfomanceService : INotificationService 
{
    private System.Timers.Timer heartbeat;
    private TimeSpan heartbeatInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    private CancellationTokenSource source;
    private CancellationToken token;
    private IProgress<string> progress;

    public PerfomanceService(TimeSpan notificationPeriod, 
        CancellationToken token, IProgress<string> progress) {
        this.token = token;
        this.progress = progress;
        NotificationPeriod = notificationPeriod;
    }

    public void Start() {
        heartbeat = new System.Timers.Timer();
        heartbeat.Elapsed -= ExecuteServiceAction;
        heartbeat.Elapsed += ExecuteServiceAction;
        heartbeat.Interval = heartbeatInterval.Milliseconds;
        ServiceStartTime = DateTime.Now;
        heartbeat.Start();
    }

    public async void ExecuteServiceAction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UpTime = DateTime.Now - ServiceStartTime;

        // Send notifications at 06:00.
        if (!generatingReport && DateTime.Now.Hour == 6 && 
            DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second < 2) {
            try {
                generatingReport = true;
                await GenerateAtgReportAsync(); // Not shown.
            }
            finally {
                generatingReport = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop() {
        heartbeat.Stop();
    }

    public void Restart() {
        Stop();
        Start();
    }

    public System.Timers.Timer Heartbeat {
        get { return heartbeat; }
    }
    public TimeSpan NotificationPeriod { get; set; }
    public DateTime ServiceStartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan UpTime { get; set;  }
}
```

To start this I use the `Main()` method of my console app with a `ManualResetEvent` to efficiently prevent immediate exit.

```
static ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
static ManualResetEvent quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static PerfomanceService perfService;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;

    try {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eArgs) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to quit?");
            keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
                return;

            source.Cancel();
            quitEvent.Set();
            eArgs.Cancel = true;
        };

        Task.Run(() => {
            TimeSpan notificationPeriod = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
            Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => ConsoleHelpers.WriteLine(s));
            perfService = new PerfomanceService(notificationPeriod, token, progress);
            perfService.Start();
        });
        quitEvent.WaitOne();
        perfService.Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Do logging.
    }
}
```

Now, I appreciate that this timer is only ticking over at one second intervals (and I could make this less frequent), but is this overkill? I am worried that this might be using unnecessary resources (spinning a thread constantly to do the timing) so I have attempted to re-write this to use `System.Threading.Timer`.

The new `PerfomanceService` class now becomes:

```
public class PerfomanceService : INotificationService
{
    private System.Threading.Timer heartbeat;
    private TimeSpan heartbeatInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    private CancellationTokenSource source;
    private CancellationToken token;
    private IProgress<string> progress;

    public PerfomanceService(TimeSpan notificationPeriod, 
        CancellationToken token, IProgress<string> progress) {
        this.token = token;
        this.progress = progress;
        NotificationPeriod = notificationPeriod;
    }

    public void Start() {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime sendTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hour);
        long msUntilSendTime = (long)(sendTime - now).TotalMilliseconds;

        heartbeat = new System.Threading.Timer(
            new TimerCallback(ExecuteServiceAction), null, msUntilSendTime, (long)Timeout.Infinite);
        ServiceStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public async void ExecuteServiceAction(object state) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime sendTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hour);

        // If it's already past send time execute action, 
        // extend time and wait until tomorrow.
        if (now > sendTime) {
            await GenerateAtgReportAsync(); // Not shown.
            sendTime = sendTime.AddDays(1.0);
        }
        long msUntilSendTime = (long)(sendTime - now).TotalMilliseconds;
        heartbeat.Change(msUntilSendTime, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Stop() {
        heartbeat.Dispose();
    }

    public void Restart() {
        Stop();
        Start();
    }
```

Please note that I have not fully implemented the second method as I have never used `System.Threading.Timer` before and want to be sure that my methodology is right and that I can use it this way before going through and breaking my already working code.

Some questions:

1. Is my use of `System.Threading.Timer` correct?
2. Which method is better and why?
3. How can I make the second method better?

Comment: If you post a class, please make sure not to forget any variables which may be needed. In its current state I would say that neither of this `PerformanceService` classes would be on topic. The first one is missing (at least)  the `generatingReport` variable and the second is missing the `hour` variable, both used in the `ExecuteServiceAction` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use either of them.

The timers are meant for short term intervals and aren't suited for scheduling tasks running daily. They do not account for timezone offsets changing or leap seconds being added.

Use the Windows Task Scheduler to set up a task that is run at the desired time and interval. Use it to trigger a console application that generates the report.

Let Windows keep up with the ever changing time.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like the `System.Timers.Timer` better because I find it tidier and more elegant.

Instead of manually wiring up some delegate that takes a state of type `Object`, which you would do for the `System.Threading` one, you get the event pattern and a handy `EventArgs` of type `ElapsedEventArgs` which contains the time the event was fired. Side note: I noticed you sometimes store `DateTime.Now` to a variable and reference the variable and sometimes you use `DateTime.Now` multiple times. `DateTime.Now` is computed every time you reference it, so I'd avoid that. In fact, I'd completely remove all usage of `DateTime.Now` since the time you're after is provided in the argument.

As for resource consumption, the cost of firing this event periodically is extremely minimal. The only time I would worry about resource consumption would be if the check performed at each interval had some kind of significant memory footprint. Inspecting a `DateTime` is about as low-cost as you can get.

I would make the Timer tick every minute, check if the time provided in the `ElapsedEventArgs` is 6 AM, and then send off the email if so.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to read my question, it is most appreciated. I like the former solution better too, based on what you have said, I have changed the tick rate to 15 minutes and switched to `DateTime now = DateTime.Now;` to avoid re-calculation. I always blindly thought `DateTime.Now` was retrieved from the OS, so inexpensive!

Comment: Why not change your method signature to `(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)` and then check `e.SignalTime`? It'll be *even faster*!

Comment: I prefer to use `System.Timers.Timer` too  but with the release of .NET Core, it seems to be gone! For this reason, I think that you should use `System.Threading.Timer` for future development.